# Querying XML column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2, xquery

I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2, and have a table that I audit update statements.

```
create table STG_Participant_16_Month
(
Serial                  int,
ID                      varchar(10),
StartTime               datetime, 
FinishTime              datetime, 
ChildID                 varchar(10),
childIndex              int,
Record_State            varchar(15),
Duplicate_flag          varchar(1)
);
```

When table X is updated, it inserts a record into an audit table:

```
select * 
into STG_Participant_16_Month_AUDIT 
from STG_Participant_16_Month;

alter table STG_Participant_16_Month_AUDIT
add audit_user                       varchar(30),
    audit_action                     varchar(1),
    audit_date                       datetime,
    columns_updated                  xml;
```

I create a record and do an update:

```
insert into STG_Participant_16_Month
( Serial, ID, StartTime, FinishTime, ChildID, childIndex,
  Record_State, Duplicate_flag )
values
(  90, 'ID', getdate(), getdate(), 'ChildID', 1,
  'LOADED', 'N');

update STG_Participant_16_Month set serial=99, ID='xx', childIndex=99  where serial=90;
```

I see output as follows:

```
<Fields>
  <Field Name="Serial" />
  <Field Name="ID" />
  <Field Name="childIndex" />
</Fields>
```

How do I create a query which just shows the text values?

```
Serial
ID
childIndex
```

Comment: output is:    <Fields>
  <Field Name="Serial" />
  <Field Name="ID" />
  <Field Name="childIndex" />
</Fields>

Answer (score 0):

IF that's your output, then it looks like your trigger is not populating the XML file correctly; I tried to guess what your output might look like, and built an xQuery SQL statement to demonstrate:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( x XML )

INSERT  INTO @t
        SELECT  '<Fields> <Field Name="Serial">99</Field> <Field Name="ID">xx</Field> <Field Name="childIndex">99</Field> </Fields>'
SELECT  x
FROM    @t

SELECT  Serial = x.value('data(for $f in //Field 
                where $f/@Name="Serial"
                return $f)[1]', 'int')
      , ID = x.value('data(for $f in //Field 
                where $f/@Name="ID"
                return $f)[1]', 'varchar(2)')
      , childIndex = x.value('data(for $f in //Field 
                where $f/@Name="childIndex"
                return $f)[1]', 'int')
FROM    @t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    UpdFld.value('(@Name)', 'varchar(20)')
FROM 
    STG_Participant_16_Month_AUDIT
CROSS APPLY
    COLUMNS_UPDATED.nodes('/Fields/Field') AS Tbl(UpdFld)
```

It grabs a list of all the `<Field>` nodes inside the root `<Fields>` node, and extracts the `Name` attribute from those XML elements.

I get an output something like this:

[image]